# How to export filename together with variable?

Tags: bash, shell, command

My code is:

```
a = 5335672
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > file_master_echo $a .txt
```

Finally, I want output filename to be:

```
file_master_5335672.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of using `echo` there (also must point that is not the proper way to use it). In addition, you [cannot leave blank spaces when defining a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258727/spaces-in-variable-assignments-in-shell-scripts). That said, just try:

```
a=5335672
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > file_master_$a.txt
```